# Margin of Error and C.I

Tags: r, statistics

It is assumed that the following data fits a Normal Distribution Curve:

```
345.35 346.25 351.65 341.75 347.00 288.95 342.50 330.35 326.85 341.25
329.55 327.85 329.00 363.50 341.25 329.90 324.50 338.90 331.60 
333.80
343.45 352.35 351.95 289.90 331.75 336.75 341.65 356.75 330.95 
360.25
297.25 348.95 324.50 338.90 331.60 333.80
```

I want to do an estimation of the Mean by establishing a margin of error and a confidence interval, using a 95% confidence-level.

I know how to do this by hand but can anyone help me with the r code?

I have already found the following statistics in r.

```
`mean(AC);`
## [1] 335.625
`var(AC);`
## [1] 278.8489
`sd(AC);`
## [1] 16.69877
```

Thank you to anyone experienced in stats to help me with this!

Comment: This is more of a stats question, maybe: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86509/calculating-confidence-intervals-for-two-samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> x <- c(345.35,346.25,351.65,341.75,347.00,288.95,342.50,330.35,326.85,341.25,
+ 329.55,327.85,329.00,363.50,341.25,329.90,324.50,338.90,331.60 ,
+ 333.80,343.45 ,352.35, 351.95, 289.90 ,331.75, 336.75 ,341.65, 356.75 ,330.95 ,
+ 360.25,
+ 297.25, 348.95 ,324.50 ,338.90, 331.60 ,333.80)
> n <- length(x)
> s <- sd(x)
> s
[1] 16.69877
> mu <- mean(x)
> mu
[1] 335.625
> error <- qnorm(0.975)*s/sqrt(n)
> mu-error
[1] 330.1702
> mu+error
[1] 341.0798
```

Comment: Is that a 95% competence level or a 97.5 CL?

Comment: you need 2.5% on each tail for calculating 95% CI